# Xamarin: Bridging C# with a native Android library

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xmpp, bridge

Though I have been developing on the .Net platform for years now, I am more or less a newbie when it comes to mobile development.

I am developing a cross-platform messaging app using Xamarin, and the app relies heavily on XMPP for updates from the server. I have looked around a bit, however there seems to be no XMPP library that has been ported to Xamarin yet. (I am specifically looking for a free library.) I wanted to know if it is possible to build some kind of a bridge between Xamarin's C# code and the [Smack XMPP library for Android](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack). Once I have an idea how to do this, iOS should not be much of a challenge.

Of course, this could have been a more generic question: is it possible to bridge Xamarin's C# code with a native Android library?

Any pointers will be of immense help.

Comment: use a binding library - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/

Comment: That's a very helpful document. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of libraries available for c#. I am an author myself of one of them.
See also here as a start for a (incomplete) list:

https://xmpp.org/software/libraries.html